# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to run the sample of Google Cloud Messaging, which follows the tutorial from official website https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html. However, the sample suddenly crash and generate the error as following:

[image: Error Generated by Logcat]

After tracing, I found the error in this block of code:

```
     /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I've also followed the guide to set up Google Play Service https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and I've done the following so far:

- Copy the "google-play-services_lib" into Eclipse workspace.
- Reference the "google-play-services_lib" into the sample project.

[image: Referencing "google-play-services_lib"]

I've done this many times and been searching for solution for a few days now, it is driving me crazy. Please HELP!!! :(

P.S: I'm using physical device to test, tested on my LG G3 and Galaxy S4.

Comment: Running on an emulator or a physical device ?

Comment: oh... i forgot to mention, physical device... sorry was trying to simplified n make the question easy to understand @JayeshElamgodil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying on many solution, finally I've come to my own fix. The solution goes as below.

1. Change your VM values in "\eclipse\eclipse.ini" as below:

   openFile
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   512M
   -showsplash
   org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Xms512m
   -Xmx1024m
2. Follow https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html to set up and reference the "google-play-services_lib" into your project. Final output should be something like the image below:

[image]

3. Add "google-play-services.jar" from "google-play-services_lib/libs" (according to step 2, after you imported the project into your workspace) into your build path as picture below:

[image]

[image]

4. Finally, check "google-play-services.jar" in "Order and Export" tab of Java Build Path:

[image]

I hope this solution could help fellow android dev, as it got me frustrated since I followed the guide from google, but the app keep crashing :D

Cheers

Comment: but when I check "google-play-services.jar" in "Order and Export" tab of Java Build Path I am getting error as "Java heap Space". And when I uncheck this jar from Java Build Path my app is crashing because of  GooglePlayServicesUtil not found. also I replaced values of eclipse.ini settings also. Please, help me what will be solution?

Comment: @Mohini i also got the heap space error before i changed "eclipse.ini" as well. Can you make a copy of your "eclipse.ini" file in the comment?

Comment: -startup 
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product 
org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product  
--launcher.defaultAction  
openFile  
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize  
1048M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1048M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
--vmargs
-VM_ARGS="-XX:-UseParallelGC -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"

Comment: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xverify:none
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-XX:MaxNewSize=128m
-XX:NewSize=128m    
-Xms512M
-Xmx1048M

Comment: @Mohini it seems you have changed the "eclipse.ini" as I posted. Maybe you should upgrade your Eclipse, since I'm using Eclipse Luna. Oh and don't forget to change the "eclipse.ini" after you've download the later version of Eclipse. Sorry, I couldn't help you :(

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your device has the Google Play Services app installed and also it has the same version as installed in your project.

Also check the minSDK and TargetSDK in the manifest file does not exceed or precede API levels.

Do not miss this tag in Manifest:

```
<application
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks @AniV for your reply. But I tested on 2 physical devices which I have mentioned thus, Google Play Services app is pre-installed.

minSDK and targetSDK in manifest shouldn't have anything to with the error in the error log i've posted.

and as I had mentioned, I followed the official guide from google, therefore I am not missing the tag.

Answer (score -2):

To test Google Play Services you'll need to be running on a physical device with Google Play Services installed.